# Replace and update Postgresql tables using SQLAlchemy and python data-frames

Tags: python, postgresql, dataframe, sqlalchemy, overwrite

I have a python script which brings data from mongodb, elaborate it and write the final results into a postgresql db as a table:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@localhost/db')
df.to_sql("table", engine)
```

The code functions perfectly but when i rerun the code it gives an error that the table already exists.

My question is what are the necessary commands to let it either overwrite the existing table or just update it with new rows?

Answer (score 1):

I found a very simple answer which do the trick in [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

```
df.to_sql("table", engine, if_exists='replace')
```

The default setting is if table exists session fails